# display : inline on MDN CSS

Tags: css

I was reading about css' `display` on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display), where I came across this line :

> **display : inline**  |  The element generates one or more inline element boxes.

What is the meaning of this? What boxes are being talked about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a picture will make it clear.

http://jsfiddle.net/3PGLd/2/

HTML

```
<div>
<div class="inline">HI</div>
<div class="inline">HELLO</div>
<div class="inline">HOWDY</div>
</div>
<div>
<div class="block">BYE</div>
<div class="block">GOODBYE</div>
<div class="block">TATA</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inline{
display: inline;
border: 1px solid;
}
.block {
display: block;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

`inline` allows space for more elements to come on the same horizontal line. `block` blocks the whole horizontal area.

Comment: Why do you say that? The article says "In HTML, default `display` property values are taken from behaviors described in the HTML specifications or from the browser/user default stylesheet." which confirms your statement, no?

Comment: My bad, I didn't see they were describing `display` for XML and not HTML.